# Converting pedometer Activity to work in Fragment

Tags: android, android-service

I am working off of [this](https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer/tree/master/src/name/bagi/levente/pedometer) GitHub project and trying to convert the pedometer code to run in a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`.

[Here](https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer/blob/master/src/name/bagi/levente/pedometer/Pedometer.java) is the main activity code which I'm trying to convert to running inside a `Fragment`.

I've made minor changes to have it run in a `Fragment`, such as moving the instantiation of layout objects such as `TextView`s into `onCreateView()`, using a `Context` reference from the `Activity` with the service, etc. Small changes leaving the main code the same.

The code compiles and runs with no errors but the `TextView`s don't show anything, so I'm not sure if it's counting steps.

I think maybe the problem is the `Service`, but I'm new to `Services` so I'm not sure what's wrong, especially since there are no errors/crashes. I'd appreciate any advice on how to convert this to run in a `Fragment`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I"m fairly new to android, but have you checked the variables themselves to make sure they are updating correctly in the fragment? Or are the textviews just completely blank?

Comment: The TextViews are completely blank where the count for steps/pace/distance should go. The subtitles such as "miles/hour" appear. Which led me to believe it was a problem with the Service.